# babel Promise polyfill not working with webpack modules: false

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Here is my `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 9"]
      },
      "useBuiltIns": true,
      "modules": false
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

In my code I've included the polyfill module.

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
```

Running my app in IE11 results in the following error.

> SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined

When I remove `"modules": false` everything works fine. I thought this option simply tells webpack not to transpile ES6 into ES5 modules which is required for treeshaking.

Why do the polyfills stop working?

Comment: Are you using Axios?

Comment: No I'm not using Axios. Does it matter?

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/135 That's why I asked.

Comment: I know all that stuff. `"modules": false` is key / the problem here.

Comment: You can check where Promise is actually used in transpiled code, can't you? Otherwise the answerer has to do this for you. And probably won't succeed at that because his/her build may not have this problem.